# SQL Server Clustered Index

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I was going through a nice article that explained about SQL Server clustered index. The article reads as below:-

*SQL Server clustered index holds all data pages at Leaf level. So, when the SQL predicate uses the indexed column, all columns of the table can be retrieved from the index itself.*

Does it mean index replicates the data already stored in data files in it's own storage space or just logically link the data file pages with the index? Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Short answer: the latter. If a clustered index is present, the table *is* the leaf pages of the clustered index (with non-leaf pages as the upper levels of the B-tree).

Comment: When quoting an article, it really helps if you cite it; then we can get the full quote if needed and future readers will be able to read the full article if your question is helpful.